# how i can retrieve all woocommerce orders in new custom plugin

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, plugins

i'm creating a new custom plugin and need to retrieve all woocommerce orders

i tried to use :  `wc_get_orders()` function to retrieve all woocommerce orders but i got

```
Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function wc_get_orders()
```

and did this :

```
require_once '../woocommerce/includes/wc-order-functions.php';
```

but i got :

```
require_once(../woocommerce/includes/wc-order-functions.php): failed to open stream:
```

**how i can retrieve all woocommerce orders**

Comment: Take a look at: https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/wiki/wc_get_orders-and-WC_Order_Query. **A hint:** "Too few arguments to function `wc_get_orders()`, 0 passed in and exactly 1 expected". **Another hint:** `$orders = wc_get_orders( array( 'customvar' => 'somevalue' ) );`

Comment: thanks for assistants 
i tried to use and got this error $query = new WC_Order_Query( array(
    'limit' => 10,
    'orderby' => 'date',
    'order' => 'DESC',
    'return' => 'ids',
) );
$orders = $query->get_orders();

Uncaught Error: Class 'WC_Order_Query' not found ...

is there any include or use i should to do ?

Comment: You can try this: https://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/?shell#list-all-orders

Comment: The code itself works, however, the information that is missing from your question is from where and how you apply this code. If you added the code into `functions.php` it should work without any problems. So it seems that the problem is not with the code but with its use

Comment: i'm creating a custom plugin , and need to list all orders

Comment: Well, as I already indicated, the fault seems to lies with your custom plugin, about how you created or applied it. That is the information that is missing in your question

Comment: okay i will edit the question

Comment: While you’re at it, you could fix the text formatting. There is really no good reason to make _everything_ bold.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WooCommerce already provided API to get all orders `https://example.com/wp-json/wc/v3/orders`

For more details please see the [documentation](https://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/?shell#list-all-orders)

---

If you want function based instead of REST API then, please do like this:

You should call your order function into the action hook `woocommerce_after_register_post_type` to work properly. So please enclose your function call like this:

```
add_action(
    'woocommerce_after_register_post_type', 
    function() {
        $orders = wc_get_orders( array( 'numberposts' => -1 ) );
        var_dump( $orders );
    }
);
```

---

Then you can loop through the object and fetch all the necessary details for e.g.

```
foreach ( $orders->get_items() as $item_id => $item ) {
   $product_id = $item->get_product_id();
   $variation_id = $item->get_variation_id();
   $product = $item->get_product();
   $name = $item->get_name();
   $quantity = $item->get_quantity();
   $subtotal = $item->get_subtotal();
   $total = $item->get_total();
   $tax = $item->get_subtotal_tax();
   $taxclass = $item->get_tax_class();
   $taxstat = $item->get_tax_status();
   $allmeta = $item->get_meta_data();
   $somemeta = $item->get_meta( '_whatever', true );
   $type = $item->get_type();
}
```

For more details please check this [article](https://www.businessbloomer.com/woocommerce-easily-get-order-info-total-items-etc-from-order-object/).

Comment: i got this Call to undefined function wc_get_orders()

Comment: i need to list the orders in a custom plugin --
i should include something ?

Comment: Kindly share your WooCommerce version

Comment: the version is 4.5.2

Comment: You have to call your function inside the action hook `woocommerce_after_register_post_type` please check the updated answer

Comment: many thanks -- do you know how to solve it this .. Call to a member function get_items()

Comment: Generic one difficult to say why it occurs post new question with the stack trace and when/which event it occurs.